# Tera Term のマクロでシンタックスエラーが発生する

Tags: teraterm

teratermマクロでログを1つのテキストファイルに追記で取ろうとしておりますが、
なぜか、毎回、シンタックスエラーと出てしまい、ログの中断、取得するかのダイアログが出てしまいます。
ログを保存するための.logファイル名も間違いはありません。

原因が分かる方、アドバイスをお願い致します。

```
changedir 'C:\test\aaa\'
LOGFILNAME = 'sample.log'
strconcat LOGFILNAME

logopen LOGFILNAME 0 1
sendln 'date'
pause 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strconcat`の引数は２個だと思います。
ログファイルのパス名を生成したいのなら`getdir`が使えると思います。

https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/4/ja/macro/command/getdir.html
https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/4/ja/macro/command/strconcat.html

`sendln 'date'`はdateという文字をログに残したいのでしょうか？

https://teraterm.jp/manual/4.75/html/macro/command/getdate.html

Comment: strconcat LOGFILNAMEは不要で、タスクスケジューラーの引数設定を修正し無事解決できました。